# Update DataGrid inside AJAX accordion

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, ajaxcontroltoolkit, edititemtemplate

I have an AJAX accordion from the ajax control toolkit on a page with a datagrid inside on of the panels.  I have a custom itemtemplate for the one column to create a multiline textbox when I click edit on the row.  When I click update on the row, the original content of the textbox gets rendered into the textbox.  It is supposed to update and go back to the literal not the textbox.  When I put the DataBind() into a !IsPostBack, it doesnt get rendered when I click on the accordion pane.  Any ideas?

Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            announ.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "header";
                        announ.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                        announ.GridLines = GridLines.None;
                        announ.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                        announ.CellPadding = 10;
                        announ.CellSpacing = 0;
                        announ.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                        announ.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
                        announ.EnableViewState = false;
                        announ.AlternatingItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GhostWhite;
                        //announ.DeleteCommand += AnnounDeleteCommand;
                        announ.EditCommand += announ_EditCommand;
                        announ.UpdateCommand += announ_UpdateCommand;
                        announ.CancelCommand += announ_CancelCommand;
                        announ.DataKeyField = "id";
                        var tc1 = new TemplateColumn
                                      {
                                          HeaderTemplate = new
                                              DataGridTemplate(ListItemType.Header, "Announcement"),
                                          ItemTemplate = new DataGridTemplate(ListItemType.Item, "announcement_text"),
                                          EditItemTemplate = new
                                              DataGridTemplate(ListItemType.EditItem, "announcement_text")
                                      };



                    var editColumn = new EditCommandColumn
                                         {
                                             ButtonType = ButtonColumnType.PushButton,
                                             HeaderText = "Edit",
                                             EditText = "Edit",
                                             UpdateText = "Update",
                                             CancelText = "Cancel"
                                         };
    var dateColumn = new BoundColumn {HeaderText = "Posted On", DataField = "date", ReadOnly = true};
                    var expirationColumn = new BoundColumn {HeaderText = "Expiration Date", DataField = "expiration_date"};
    announ.Columns.Add(tc1);
                    announ.Columns.Add(dateColumn);
                    announ.Columns.Add(expirationColumn);
    announ.DataSource = myAnnouncements;
                    announ.DataBind();

var deptMgtaccord = new Accordion
                                        {
                                            ID = "deptMgtaccord",
                                            HeaderCssClass = "accordion-header",
                                            HeaderSelectedCssClass = "accordion-headerSelected",
                                            AutoSize = AutoSize.None,
                                            SelectedIndex = 0,
                                            FadeTransitions = true,
                                            TransitionDuration = 250,
                                            FramesPerSecond = 40,
                                            RequireOpenedPane = false,
                                            SuppressHeaderPostbacks = true
                                        };
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    deptMgtaccord.SelectedIndex = selected;
                }

                var announcementPane = new AccordionPane {ID = "announcementPane"};
                announcementPane.HeaderContainer.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#e3e2e2';");
                announcementPane.HeaderContainer.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';");
                announcementPane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Announcements >>"));
                announcementPane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(announ);
                deptMgtaccord.Panes.Add(announcementPane);
                var statsPane = new AccordionPane {ID = "statsPane"};
                statsPane.HeaderContainer.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#e3e2e2';");
                statsPane.HeaderContainer.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';");
                statsPane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Statistics >>"));
                statsPane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Stats"));
                deptMgtaccord.Panes.Add(statsPane);
ph1.Controls.Add(deptMgtaccord);
    }

           protected void announ_CancelCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                announ.EditItemIndex = -1;
                announ.DataBind();
            }

            protected void announ_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                var dc = new MTCDataDataContext();
                var announText = (TextBox) e.Item.Cells[1].Controls[1];
                int announId = (int)announ.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex];
                var currentAnnoun = (from a in dc.announcements
                                     where a.id == announId
                                     select a).SingleOrDefault();
                currentAnnoun.announcement_text = announText.Text;
                dc.SubmitChanges();

                announ.EditItemIndex = -1;
                announ.DataBind();
            }

            protected void announ_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                announ.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
                announ.DataBind();
            }


public class DataGridTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        ListItemType templateType;
        string columnName;
        public DataGridTemplate(ListItemType type, string colname)
        {
            templateType = type;
            columnName = colname;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            Literal lc = new Literal();
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            switch (templateType)
            {
                case ListItemType.Header:
                    lc.Text = "<B>" + columnName + "</B>";
                    container.Controls.Add(lc);
                    break;
                case ListItemType.Item:
                    lc.DataBinding += lc_DataBinding;
                    container.Controls.Add(lc);
                    break;
                case ListItemType.EditItem:
                    tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                    tb.Rows = 6;
                    tb.Columns = 57;
                    tb.DataBinding += tb_DataBinding;
                    container.Controls.Add(tb);
                    break;
                case ListItemType.Footer:
                    lc.Text = "<I>" + columnName + "</I>";
                    container.Controls.Add(lc);
                    break;
            }
        }
        void tb_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            DataGridItem row = (DataGridItem)tb.NamingContainer;
            tb.ID = "txt_" + row.ItemIndex;
            tb.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, columnName).ToString();
        }
        void lc_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Literal lc = (Literal)sender;
            DataGridItem row = (DataGridItem)lc.NamingContainer;
            lc.ID = "txt_" + row.ItemIndex;
            lc.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, columnName).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your dynamic controls in [PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) on every request in order for the controls to get back into the ControlTree and raise events.

**Page Event:**
 
PreInit

**Typical Use:**
Raised after the start stage is complete and before the initialization stage begins.

Use this event for the following:

- Check the IsPostBack property to determine whether this is the first
  time the page is being processed. The
  IsCallback and IsCrossPagePostBack
  properties have also been set at this
  time.
- ***Create or re-create dynamic controls.***
- Set a master page dynamically.
- Set the Theme property dynamically.
- Read or set profile property values.

  Note: If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet been restored from view state. If you set a control property at this stage, its value might be overwritten in the next event.